# Go to next line and replace

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string, for example:

```
String = "This is first sentence, sentence one. This is second sentence, sentence two`."
```

I want to replace "sentence" with another word from a list

```
my_list = ['1', 'me1', '2', 'me2']
```

so it will become:

```
"This is first 1, me1 one. This is second 2, me2 two."
```

Any ideas?

Comment: SO isn't a tutorial service; *what have you tried*, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: `str.replace` takes a third optional `count` argument, by setting it to 1 you can replace occurrences one at a time. Also, what if the number of occurrences of `sentence` in `String` is not equal to the length of `my_list`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String = "This is first sentence, sentence one. This is second sentence, sentence two`."
String1 = String
my_list = ['1', 'me1', '2', 'me2']

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    String1=String1.replace("sentence",my_list[i],1)
    print i, my_list[i]
print String1
```

Out put :

```
'This is first 1, me1 one. This is second 2, me2 two`.'
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `regex.sub(repl, string, count=0)` function and custom `replace_substring` function as a replacement callback:

```
def replace_substring(m):
    if replace_substring.counter == len(my_list):
        replace_substring.counter = 0

    replaced = my_list[replace_substring.counter]
    replace_substring.counter += 1
    return replaced

replace_substring.counter = 0

String = "This is first sentence, sentence one. This is second sentence, sentence two`."
my_list = ['1', 'me1', '2', 'me2']
pattern = re.compile(r'\bsentence\b')

result = pattern.sub(replace_substring, String)
print(result)
```

The output:

```
This is first 1, me1 one. This is second 2, me2 two`.
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.sub